# Tab page auto created

Tags: c#, .net

I'm retrieving some data from database

```
string query = "select select distinct size_name from master";
DataTable dt = db.select_command(query);
```

now data comes, we know i have 3 size in datatable so how to
auto generate 3 tab pages in tabcontrol with Datagridview and some
columns //after that how to get the values of individual tabs columns
values //here is tabpage creating code but not automatically

```
string title = "TabPage " + (tabControl2.TabCount + 1).ToString();

TabPage myTabPage = new TabPage(title);

tabControl2.TabPages.Add(myTabPage);
DataGridView dat = new DataGridView();
dat.Width = 1260;
dat.Height = 330;
dat.Columns.Add("id", "ID");
dat.Columns.Add("color_name", "Color Name");
dat.Columns.Add("quantity", "Quantity");
dat.Columns.Add("no_carton", "Carton No");
dat.Columns.Add("weight", "Weight");
dat.Columns.Add("percent_waste", "Percent Waste");
dat.Columns.Add("total_weight", "Total Weight");
dat.Columns.Add("ean_no", "EAN NO");
dat.Columns.Add("article_code", "Article Code");
dat.Columns.Add("yarn", "Yarn");
dat.Columns.Add("size_name", "Size Name");
dat.Columns.Add("ctn_size", "Carton Size");
dat.Columns.Add("color_no", "Color No");
dat.Columns.Add("thrd", "Thrd");
myTabPage.Controls.Add(dat);
```

Comment: i have 3 sizes when form load 3 tabs created else if have 4 so for tabs created size my table column name

Answer (score 0):

Loop through your result and add a tabpage to your tabcontrol for each result in your DataTable.

```
foreach(DataRow row in dt.Rows){
//method for creating tab / adding tab to tabcontrol
}
```

Comment: yes i tried this but each size has many rows and data how can i set the data of each size on same tab page of size

Comment: @naeem The query gives you X amount of rows with every row having a single cell containing a 'size value'? Or is your desired result X amount of rows ordered by your 'size values'. You should first get clear what exact information you want to show on each tabpage and base your search query on  that those facts.